# C++ using placement new causes segmentation fault in constructor

Tags: c++17, placement-new, constructor-overloading

please find below code. In this code, when I use "placement new", the I see segmentation fault in constructor, I am not sure why it is causing this, since I can create normal objects. Also, if I use new operator, the code works. Issue is only with placement new. Can someone help me understand this behavior?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
template<typename T=int>
class LessThan{
    public:
    LessThan(T x):mem(x){}
    bool operator()(T x){
        return x < mem;
    }

    private:
    T mem;
};

int main(){
    LessThan a(9);
    cout<<"less than 9: "<<a(10)<<endl;
    cout<<"less than 9: "<<a(8)<<endl;
    LessThan<int>* b = nullptr;// = new LessThan(11);
    new(b) LessThan<int>(11);
    if(b == nullptr){
        cout<<"b is null..."<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"less than 11: "<<(*b)(12)<<endl;
    cout<<"less than 11: "<<(*b)(8)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: new(nullptr) is always going to cause a segmentation fault.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: _"please find below code"_ I found it! What's my prize? Anyhow, what do you think placement new does? It uses the allocated space for a new object. But if nothing is allocated, this is UB

Comment: You should know that `new(nullptr)` tries to dereference the memory address zero that is not allowed in most of the platforms. Even if your program doesn't crash you still need to be worried because that's undefined behavior in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> LessThan<int>* b = nullptr;// = new LessThan(11);
> new(b) LessThan<int>(11);
> ```

I'm not sure what kind of trick you are trying to achieve when passing a `nullptr` into `new` operator, but when using the `placement new` operator, you are supposed to allocate enough space (and align it properly) to fit in an instance of your class. The pointer should point to the allocated memory, not just an empty pointer of the given class:

```
char memory[sizeof(LessThan<int>)];
new(memory) LessThan<int>(11);
```